# Show/Hide label based on value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my project I have situation where I have to check value of my input and then show/hide elements. Here is my HTML code:

```
<td>
  <label class="test1">
    <input type="radio" name="reservation" class="bls" id="bls_1" value="10"/>
  </label>
  <label class="test2" style="display:none">
    <span>John, Cook</span>
  </label>
</td>

<td>
  <label class="test1">
    <input type="radio" name="reservation" class="bls" id="bls_2" value="0"/>
  </label>
  <label class="test2" style="display:none">
    <span></span>
  </label>
</td>
```

Here is my JQuery:

```
$('.bls').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() > 0){
        $(this).parent('.test1').hide();
        $('.test2').show();
    }
});
```

My current code hide radio button based on the values but I have a problem with `show()` effect. I want only element in the same td to show.

My current code display all label with class name `test2`. I want to display label only for td where my value is greater than 0. How that can be done in JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to chain the `next()` and `show()` from `this` object,

```
$('.bls').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() > 0){
       $(this).parent('.test1').hide().next('.test2').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You would just do the same as you did for the `hide()` method and use `this`:

```
$(this).closest('td').find('.test2').show();
```

Comment: `$(this).parent('td')` will not work. Use `.closest()` instead

Comment: Thanks @RajaprabhuAravindasamy . Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to get the parent `td` then find the label with class `test2` and show it :

```
$(this).closest('td').find('.test2').show();
```

Full code :

```
$('.bls').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() > 0){
       $(this).parent('.test1').hide();
       $(this).closest('td').find('.test2').show();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.